# Pass anonymous callback function as argument into function?

Tags: php, function, callback, anonymous-function

I wanna send a function into another function to be executed later inside that function. The idea is similar to callback success functions in jQuery.

The idea is this:

```
function my_function($args)
{
    // ...

    // Code that creates the $result variable

    // ..

    // Execute the calback function, how??:
    $args['callback_function']; // Handle the $result
}

$args = array(
    'callback_function' => function($result)
                            {
                                // $result created in my_function()
                            }
);
my_function($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own example you can do it like this...

```
function my_function($args)
{
    $res= "your value here";

    $args['callback_function']($res); // Handle the $result
}

$args = array(
    'callback_function' => function($result)
                            {
                                var_dump($result);
                            }
);
my_function($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$args['callback_function']($result);
```

Or like this:

```
call_user_func($args['callback_function'], $result);
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

### Example

```
function my_function($args)
{
    // ...
    // Code that creates the $result variable
    $result = 1;
    // ...

    call_user_func($args['callback_function'], $result);
}

$args = array(
    'callback_function' => function($result) {
        echo ++$result;
    }
);

my_function($args);
```

### Output

```
2
```